# Filter out rows only when two columns meet two different conditions

Tags: google-bigquery, logical-operators, conditional-operator

Assuming I have a huge table with a bunch of combinations and it looks like this

| Row | Location | Toy | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | China | A | day1 |
| 2 | China | B | day1 |
| 3 | USA | A | day1 |
| 4 | USA | B | day1 |
| 5 | France | B | day2 |
| 6 | France | A | day1 |

When pulling data, I need to filter out some of the "pairs" in two columns (Location and Toy). How can I query the table to exclude rows where the values in the columns BOTH meet particular values? I've tried getting multiple ands together but it doesn't work. This is what I tried:

```
Select * from  TABLE 
where Date = day1 
and ((Location != 'China' and Toy != 'B')) 
and ((Location != 'USA' and Toy != 'A'))
and ((Location != 'France' and Toy != 'A'))
```

So in this case, I would expect it to return rows 1 and 4, but it does not.

*Note, the script/exceptions are generated from a different code that is scheduled to run multiple times, so they are all dynamic and continuously change. I know I can easily do this in python straight in the dataframe, but I would rather pull the data clean to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try below:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM sample_table 
 WHERE Date = 'day1'
   AND (Location, Toy) NOT IN (('China', 'B'), ('USA', 'A'), ('France', 'A'));

+----------+-----+------+
| Location | Toy | Date |
+----------+-----+------+
| China    | A   | day1 |
| USA      | B   | day1 |
+----------+-----+------+
```